# SQL Query conversion from sybase to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sybase

```
select a.dda_pk
from direct_table a      
where a.dda_type = 'B'  
  and a.dda_status = 'D'        
  and a.dda_location = '01'      
group by a.dda_emp_idno       
having  dda_pk <  max(a.dda_pk) 
    and a.dda_status = 'D'  
    and a.dda_location = '01'
```

> Column 'direct_deposit_audit.dda_pk' is invalid in the HAVING clause
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is likely to be closed because it is not clear what you are asking. My guess is that you'd like to know what you need to change in order to get this to work in Microsoft SQL Server. At first glance, it looks like it will work fine, assuming you have the same table `direct_table` in SQL Server. Meanwhile, please look at [this helpful article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that may help you write questions that will elicit useful responses.

Comment: no it is not working when i tried the same query in sql server But the same query is working well in sybase !

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error, or unexpected results? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Do you have those tables in sql server?

Comment: yes i do have those table in sql server actually we are migrating from sybase to sql server and the query is running well in sybase but when i tried to run the same in sql server i'm getting errors

Comment: yes bob i'm getting an error as following:                                          Column 'direct_deposit_audit.dda_pk' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: try `select distinct ... where dda_pk <> (select max() ....)`

Comment: hi ivan can you elaborate it easily or can you change the original query to what you are trying to say ?

Comment: select a.dda_emp_idno,a.dda_pk from direct_table a      
    where 
          a.dda_type = 'B' and 
          a.dda_status = 'D' and 
          a.dda_location = '01'      
    group by 
          a.dda_emp_idno,a.dda_pk      
    having  
          a.dda_pk <  max(a.dda_pk)

Comment: The error message explains exactly what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a assumption that the SQL returns rows for each dda_emp_idno
where dda_pk is smaller than the maximum dda_pk for that dda_emp_idno.

This should do the same thing in SQL Server:

```
select dda_pk 
from (
    select 
      dda_pk, 
      dense_rank() over (partition by dda_emp_idno order by dda_pk desc) as RN  
    from 
      direct_table a
    where 
      a.dda_type = 'B'
      and a.dda_status = 'D'
      and a.dda_location = '01'
) X
where RN > 1
```

Comment: it is doing the same thing but i'm not able to see any data in the output

Comment: and when i'm running the original query it is display some data till group by clause but when i'm running the whole query i'm getting no data in the output.

Comment: my original query is returning 5 tables in sybase and in sql server it is not displaying any data .

Comment: Is my assumption about the query correct? Or what exactly does it return / do?

Comment: your asssumption is correct , the query returns dda_pk which is  smaller than the maximum dda_pk for he particular dda_emp_idno.

Comment: So if you run the inner query, it should have number 1 for the rows with the maximum value, and others have a bigger value -- and then the outer query should remove the rows with 1. If there's something else going on, you should be able to fix it.

Comment: yes the query is running well in sybase but i did check line by line in sql server and there  was some data returning till group by and after going to having statement it is returning no data where as in sybase it is returning 5 tables of dda_pk.

Comment: And i tried many ways still not able to fix the issue and i dont know whether it is problem with data or any other as the query is quiet simple

Comment: i'm talking about the original query , i tried your query nothing is returning when i used you query !

Comment: Please read my comments and try what I suggested. Talking about the original doesn't help at all.

Comment: yup i will try and get back to you :)

Answer (score -1):

All the elements in group by must be in select clause so you can try this:

```
select a.dda_pk
from direct_table a      
where a.dda_type = 'B'  
and a.dda_status = 'D'        
and a.dda_location = '01'      
group by a.dda_pk       
having  a.dda_pk <  max(a.dda_pk) 
    and a.dda_status = 'D'  
    and a.dda_location = '01'
```

Comment: still i'm getting the same error after doing the changes which you have asked me to do !

Comment: @MANIKANTAYADAV Please check my query now, edited now

Answer (score -1):

Without having dug into this query, let me just note that Sybase ASE has much looser semantics around the GROUP BY than most other databases. This means that queries with GROUP BY that run iN ASE may raise an error in other databases. 
For more info, see http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.7/title.htm